# How can I get Julian year using JodaTime?

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm writing an Java sample application where I want Julian year and Julian week in number.  can someone help me, How I calculate Julian year and  Julian week using JodaTime.

Comment: Out of interest, why are you using Julian years?

Comment: I could understand using [Julian _days_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day); along with Unix timestamps (which are a bit too precise for some purposes) they're the only sane way to calculate with time.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs

```
Chronology chrono = JulianChronology.getInstance();
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1066, 10, 14, 10, 0, 0, 0, chrono);
```

The link is [here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/cal_julian.html)

Then you can use [weekOfWeekYear()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#weekOfWeekyear%28%29) on DateTime to get the week of the year